# cannot pass arguments to gcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc, argument-passing

i am fresh in gcc programming and i want to compile a .c file with my compiler. but i dont know how?
in this case my "main" part starts this like:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int i,j,k;

int epsilon,bestepsilon;

float soundness=0,bestsoundness=0;

if (argc!=3) {

    printf("[usage] : %s <datasetname> <bestepsilon> \n", argv[0]);

    exit(1);

}

readPoints(argv[1]);

readDatainfo(argv[1]);
if (bestepsilon==0) {

for(epsilon=INITIALEPSILON; epsilon<=FINALEPSILON; epsilon++) { ...
```

but "INITIALEPSILON" and "FINALEPSILON" are not defines in this program and i should pass them from other file.

some body help me please.

i have a "makefile" that is as below:

```
DEFINE1=-DMINDIM=2 -DMAXDIM=20 -DMEANDIM=10 -DNCLUSTER=5 -DNPOINTS=100000 -DMINSIZE=5000
DEFINE2=-DFOUTLIER=0.1 -DSPREADPARAM=2 -DSCALEMAX=2 -DNSHARE=2 
com.o:../src/com.c
$(CC) -c ../src/com.c
linpack.o:../src/linpack.c
$(CC) -c ../src/linpack.c
randlib.o:../src/randlib.c
$(CC) -c ../src/randlib.c
gendata:gendata.c ../src/com.o ../src/linpack.o ../src/randlib.o
$(CC) $(DEFINE1) $(DEFINE2) -g -o gendata gendata.c ../src/com.o ../src/linpack.o ../src/randlib.o -lm
```

this make gendata that generate data set.

after that i need the findit.c that i describe it above. iwant to pass parameters like mindim from makefile to findit to compile.

Comment: include `header` file which contain it.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use `gcc -DINITIALEPSILON=0 -DFINALEPSILON=100 ...`.

Comment: Keep it in a header file in the same folder and #include "headerfile.h" in the first line

Comment: i have a "makefile" that includes these parameters but it is used for generating the data set which will be used in this file.
in fact i have one code for generating data name "gendata.c" and it is generated by makefile like this:
CC=gcc
DEFINE1=-DMINDIM=2 -DMAXDIM=20 -DMEANDIM=10 -DNCLUSTER=5 -DNPOINTS=100000  -DMINSIZE=5000
DEFINE2=-DFOUTLIER=0.1 -DSPREADPARAM=2 -DSCALEMAX=2 -DNSHARE=2 
randlib.o:../src/randlib.c
 $(CC) -c ../src/randlib.c
gendata:gendata.c  ../src/randlib.o
 $(CC) $(DEFINE1) $(DEFINE2) -g -o gendata gendata.c ../src/com.o ../src/linpack.o ../src/randlib.o -lm

Comment: @Stv1368 please paste this output in question window.

Comment: how can i add other question here?

Comment: @Stv1368: you can *edit* your question

Comment: @Stv1368 you can compile `findit.c` as same `gendata.c` but with `-DINITIALEPSILON=1 -DFINALEPSILON=1` option

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by @Jonathan Leffler

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int  main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   printf("%d   %d\n",INITIALEPSILON,FINALEPSILON);
}
```

compile

```
$ gcc -DINITIALEPSILON=100 -DFINALEPSILON=500 test.c -o test
```

run

```
$ ./test
100 500
```

Comment: i have this parameters in a file and want to use them from there.

Comment: @Stv1368 if you have it in your header file then include it